# Can I write Ito's Lemma as a taylor expension?

Tags: itos-lemma

instead of using Wikipedia's definition:
$$
{d}(f(X_t,t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(X_t,t)\,\mathrm{d}t + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(X_t,t) \, \mathrm{d}X_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(X_t,t)\sigma_t^2 \, \mathrm{d}t.$$

Can I write it like that:

$$
d(f(X_t,t)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial Xt} \, \mathrm{d}Xt + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Xt^2} \, \mathrm{d}Xt^2$$

Thanks

Comment: What do you think could be wrong with your expression $df = (\cdots) df + (\cdots) (df)^2$?

Comment: I edited the equation, sorry !

Comment: What about now ? is it correct to write Ito's lemma like that ?

Comment: No, it's actually even more incorrect :)  If a function depends on two variables then from standard calculus $df(x,y) = f_x dx + f_y dy$ where subscripts denote partial differentiation. Ito calculus is a generalization of this, and the correct expression is as given in for instance wiki.

Comment: I fixed it for the second time, I was rusty with LaTeX ;)

Comment: Almost, you forgot the dependence on $t$, and if you include that you get the correct formula.

Comment: Xt is already dependent on t so why should I add a t term ? Wouldn't it be redundant ?

Comment: To limit the number of comments, my last comment is: $X_t$'s dependence on $t$ is a special sort of dependence. Aside from that, let's go back to basic calculus and consider the function $f(t, X(t))$ where $X(t)$ is a deterministic function of $t$, for instance $f(t,X(t)) = t+ cos(t)$ with $X(t) = cos(t)$, what would be $df$?

Comment: You can’t: please check my answer to [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/7147/848).

Comment: df = -sin(t) dXt + dt  ??

Comment: If f is just a function of the stochastic process $X_t$, then yes, you don't need to write time derivative. This is the case when solving GBM SDE - $\ln X_t$. But if f is a function of t as well then you will need to add time derivative. This is the case when dealing with say Europrean call/put options.

Answer (score 7):

**Ito Lemma (as 'Taylor expansion'):** For $X$ an [Ito process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#It%C3%B4_processes) and $f =
f(t, x) ∈ C^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ a deterministic function, the stochastic process
$$Y_t = f(t,X_t)$$
is an Ito process and we have
$$df (t,X_t) = \partial_tf(t,X_t)\,dt + \partial_xf(t,X_t)\,dX_t +
\frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx}^2f(t,X_t)(dX_t)^2.  $$

*Note:* Functions

$$g(t,x)= \partial_tf(t,x), $$

$$h(t,x) = \partial_xf(t,x), $$

$$k(t,x) = \partial_{xx}^2f(t,x) $$
are also deterministic. So:

$$df (t,X_t) = g(t,X_t)\,dt + h(t,X_t)\,dX_t +
\frac{1}{2} k(t,X_t)(dX_t)^2. $$